# How to get the SharePoint List Property 'Created By' using REST api

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to display the Creator of the SharePoint List in a Project using REST API.

When I use

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')
```

I get response but, I dont find the Created By Field.
How do I know who has created the List.
Here is my Response:

```
"AllowContentTypes": true,
"BaseTemplate": 100,
"BaseType": 0,
"ContentTypesEnabled": false,
"CrawlNonDefaultViews": false,
"Created": "2014-12-03T06:58:18Z",
"DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"Description": "",
"Direction": "none",
"DocumentTemplateUrl": null,
"DraftVersionVisibility": 0,
"EnableAttachments": true,
"EnableFolderCreation": false,
"EnableMinorVersions": false,
"EnableModeration": false,
"EnableVersioning": false,
"EntityTypeName": "EmployeeList",
"ForceCheckout": false,
"HasExternalDataSource": false,
"Hidden": false,
"Id": "13cdc8f4-7fed-42eb-9a38-08c30eec6a87",
"ImageUrl": "/_layouts/15/images/itgen.png?rev=38",
"IrmEnabled": false,
"IrmExpire": false,
"IrmReject": false,
"IsApplicationList": false,
"IsCatalog": false,
"IsPrivate": false,
"ItemCount": 2,
"LastItemDeletedDate": "2014-12-03T06:58:18Z",
"LastItemModifiedDate": "2015-01-21T05:54:31Z",
"ListItemEntityTypeFullName": "SP.Data.EmployeeListItem",
"MajorVersionLimit": 0,
"MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit": 0,
"MultipleDataList": false,
"NoCrawl": false,
"ParentWebUrl": "/",
"ParserDisabled": false,
"ServerTemplateCanCreateFolders": true,
"TemplateFeatureId": "00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100",
"Title": "Employee"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In the server-side API (SSOM) and the client side APIs (REST or CSOM) the objects do not usually expose the same set of properties. This is exactly the case with List resource, where  `Author` property is not available in CSOM and REST but available in SSOM.

You could consider the following approach to retrieve `Author` property of `List` resource via REST. The idea is to get this property from List Schema as demonstrated below (*):

- First step is to retrieve List Schema: 
  `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')?$select=schemaXml`
- Then you could extract Author Id from SchemaXml property

> (*) List SchemaXml property stores `Author ID` property

**Example**

```
function getListAuthor(webUrl,listTitle)
{
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')?$select=schemaXml";
    return executeRequest(endpointUrl,'GET').then(function(data){
             var listProperties = schemaXml2Json(data.d.SchemaXml);
             return parseInt(listProperties.Author);
           });
}


//Usage: Retrieve List Author Id
getListAuthor(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Contacts')
.done(function(authorId){
    console.log('List Author Id: ' + authorId);

});
```

If List Author Id property is not enough and you would like to retrieve Author user, then you could utilize the following example:

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
getListAuthor(webUrl,'Contacts')
.then(function(authorId){
    getSiteUser(webUrl,authorId)
    .done(function(data){
         var listAuthor = data.d;
         console.log(listAuthor);
    });     
});
```

where

```
function executeRequest(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    if (typeof headers == 'undefined'){
        headers = {};
    }
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}


function schemaXml2Json(schemaXml)
{ 
    var jsonObject = {};
    var schemaXmlDoc = $.parseXML(schemaXml);
    $(schemaXmlDoc).find('List').each(function() {
      $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attr){
           jsonObject[attr.name] = attr.value;
      });
    });
    return jsonObject;
}


function getSiteUser(webUrl,userId){
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/siteUsers/getById(" + userId +  ")";
    return executeRequest(endpointUrl,'GET');
}
```

Follow [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/11/09/an-alternative-way-of-getting-client-object-properties-using-sharepoint-rest-and-csom-apis/) for a more details.

Comment: yes this way i am able to get the author , by REST 2 calls.(getting userid from schema and then get user name by another cal). But i need to display all the Lists in the Site along with the Author.
Now imagine the number of calls i may need to make :(